# Javascript API to manage Mobile Applications Lifecycle

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

I wonder to develop a JavaScript mobile application to manage applications in a cellphone.

For example, is desired to open, close running application, monitoring the time of open applications and count the times with an application as opened by period, and more few more use cases

This application should work in Android and iPhone and must be agnostic about framework, React Native, Svelte Native, Native Script, so on ...

Disclaimer: I Want to avoid to user Flutter, Kotlin/Native android or Swift, so my mission is a bit complicated.

Someone can bring the light to me about its concerns

Comment: You can't do this on iOS regardless of implementation language. An app doesn't have that level of access.

Comment: Not possible on android either